# The ole db provider used by ole db adapter cannot convert between types dt_dbtimestamp and dt_numeric in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am planning to insert current date time in SSIS project but I am getting

> The ole db provider used by ole db adapter cannot convert between types dt_dbtimestamp and dt_numeric

In my current table, CurrentDate field is datetime2(7).

```
INSERT INTO [Table](CreatedDate)
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
select ? = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: How are you planning to get the value? It looks like you're going to use an output parameter? This is an Execute SQL Task, yes? How do you have the parameter defined there? How is the SSIS variable you are mapping into defined?

Comment: I have added current date in derived column and defined it  like `CurrentDate GETDATE() database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]`

Comment: This is a Data Flow and you have this defined as an OLE DB Source? You have the rep, post a few screenshots of what you're doing as it's confusing at the moment